# EKEventStore enumerateEventsMatchingPredicate in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have following code in Objective C that fetches events from calendar. Its working code.

I migrated to Swift but fail to write the same in Swift language.

```
NSMutableArray *events = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

[_eventStore enumerateEventsMatchingPredicate:predicate
   usingBlock:^(EKEvent *event, BOOL *stop) {

       if (event)
       {
           NSUInteger fid = [events indexOfObjectPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
           {
               EKEvent *revent = (EKEvent*)obj;
               if (sameAttendees(event.attendees, revent.attendees)) // my method
               {
                   *stop = YES;
                   return YES;
               }
                return NO;
           }];

       }
   }];
```

The issue is that syntax is changed to:

```
_eventStore.enumerateEventsMatchingPredicate(predicate, usingBlock: EKEventSearchCallback!)
```

How to write `EKEventSearchCallback` in Swift?

From docs:

```
typedef void (^EKEventSearchCallback)(EKEvent *event, BOOL *stop);
```

please help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how its works:

```
_eventStore.enumerateEventsMatchingPredicate(predicate, usingBlock:{
            (event:EKEvent!, stop:UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) in

           // inner code

        }) // block
```